# Class function/procedure and instance function/procedure with the same name

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Consider this class:

```
unit u_myclass;

interface

type
  TMyClass = class
  public
    class function Foo : Integer;
    function Foo : Integer;
  end;

implementation

{ TMyClass }
class function TMyClass.Foo: Integer;
begin
 Result := 10;
end;

function TMyClass.Foo: Integer;
begin
 Result := 1;
end;

end.
```

I want to use a class function and an instance function with the same name.
Sadly Delphi doesn't like this and the compiler barfs these errors:

```
[DCC Error] u_myclass.pas(9): E2252 Method 'Foo' with identical parameters already exists
[DCC Error] u_myclass.pas(20): E2037 Declaration of 'Foo' differs from previous declaration
[DCC Error] u_myclass.pas(9): E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: 'TMyClass.Foo'
```

My Question: is this possible or is this simply a language limitation (And I need to rename one of the 2 methods)?

Comment: AFAIK, this is not possible. How should the compiler know which function you want to call? It might be obvious when you make a call to a class function, but it is not when you call it on an instance.

Comment: Good point Uwe, that must be the reason...

Comment: Just use different names. What you are trying to achieve is IMO abusing of the function overloading; it is only good that the compiler does not allow it.

Comment: @whosrdaddy - Only out of my curiosity... why? Why would you do that? I mean, what are the benefits of having a class and an instance function with the same name?

Comment: @mg30rg, well because I have to. The existing codebase has the instance method, and moving it to a class method means that I will need to rewrite a lot of code which is not feasible for now.

Comment: @user246408: I don't see no point in using two different names when the function does exactly the same thing?

Comment: Just asking (again)... Are you calling class methods like they were instance methods? I have never tried and it might be valid, but it still seem to be a bad practice. And if you are not then you still have to fix your code on every call to your method so why is it extra work to rename your method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to give use the same name for an instance method and a class method. That this is not allowed is that the compiler cannot distinguish between them in some scenarios.

For instance, if you write:

```
procedure TMyClass.Bar;
begin
  Foo;
end;
```

then the compiler cannot determine whether or not you wish to call the class method or the instance method.

Comment: Yes, @UweRaabe pointed out that already. Just wanted to be sure :)

Answer (score 2):

The only solution I found is to use overload and different parameters:

```
unit u_myclass;

interface

type
  TMyClass = class
  public
    class function Foo(A : Integer) : Integer; overload;
    function Foo : Integer; overload;
  end;

implementation

{ TMyClass }
class function TMyClass.Foo(A: Integer): Integer;
begin
 Result := A;
end;

function TMyClass.Foo: Integer;
begin
 Result := 1;
end;

end.
```

Comment: This is hardly a solution. You can hardly, in all reasonableness, expect callers to pass extra parameters that will be ignored.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: In my real world use case, it will be my solution :)

Comment: Really. You'll ask the caller to pass a parameter whose value is ignored?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: the sample code does not reflect my real world situation. In my case the parameter was needed so it is not ignored :)

Comment: Well, that changes things quite a bit. I think it's a bit odd that your answer suggests adding a parameter that will be ignored. I understand that your real world scenario is different, but we aren't considering that here. Just the question that you asked. Anyway, it's all clear I think.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I can remove my answer if you feel it doesn't fit the question?